# How do you use Boltzmanns distribution law?

Tags: dirac-delta-distributions, normalization, boltzmann-equation

Considering a particle in an isothermal atmosphere:

$ f \left( h \right) \delta \left( h \right) = A e^{\frac{-m g h}{k T}} \delta \left( h \right)$ where $A$ is the normalisation constant of the pdf.

$A \int{e^{\frac{- m g h}{k T}}} dh = 1$

from this integral, how do I get to $A = \frac{m g}{k T}$?

I feel like this should be a really simple solution, but I can't figure it out. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Change the integration variable:
$$A\int exp[-mgh/kT]dh=$$
$$=(considering\;new\;variable\;x=mgh/kT\Rightarrow dh=[kT/mg]dx)=$$
$$=A\int exp(-x)\cdot [kT/mg]dx$$
So
$$AkT/mg\int exp(-x)dx=(considering\;integral=1)=AkT/mg=1\Rightarrow A=mg/kT$$

Comment: sorry why does the integral =1? how does the exponent disappear?